# Overriding constructor in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am not sure its happening with me because i am a newbie in magento2. Every time i try to override a constructor i end with an error. Tried to find out a lot but nothing helps. So at last decided to post here.

I want to override the `execute` method of `Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View` file. Basically `category view page.`

What i am doing is

```
namespace namespace\module\Controller\Magento\Catalog\Category;

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View
{
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;
    protected $_catalogSession;
    protected $_catalogDesign;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $categoryUrlPathGenerator;
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $resultForwardFactory;
    private $layerResolver;
    protected $categoryRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Design $catalogDesign,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $categoryUrlPathGenerator,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
        Resolver $layerResolver,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_catalogDesign = $catalogDesign;
        $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->categoryUrlPathGenerator = $categoryUrlPathGenerator;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        parent::__construct($context,$storeManager,$catalogDesign,$coreRegistry,$categoryUrlPathGenerator,$resultPageFactory,$resultForwardFactory,$layerResolver,$categoryRepository);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
       // DO your code here.
    }

}
```

Now i am getting an error. Which says

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 7 passed to
>   namespace\module\Controller\Magento\Catalog\Category\View::__construct()
>   must be an instance of
>   namespace\module\Controller\Magento\Catalog\Category\PageFactory,
>   instance of Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory given

`I think this happens each time if its a factory class.` Not sure though. Do you guys have any idea why it shows.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try following way:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Category;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
     */
    protected $customerFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Design $catalogDesign
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $categoryUrlPathGenerator
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
     * @param Resolver $layerResolver
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Design $catalogDesign,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $categoryUrlPathGenerator,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
        Resolver $layerResolver,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    ) {

        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;

        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $catalogDesign,
            $catalogSession,
            $coreRegistry,
            $storeManager,
            $categoryUrlPathGenerator,
            $resultPageFactory,
            $resultForwardFactory,
            $layerResolver,
            $categoryRepository
        );
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        die('hello');
    }
}
```

**Delete var/generation/***

**N.B: Always try to use plugin, instead of overwrite whole class.**

Comment: Do you have any idea whenever i try to inject `$this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;` i get an error. Like `Magento\Customer\Model` has this. But thats not working here.

Comment: I am getting this. `Class namespace\module\Model\Customer\CustomerFactory does not exist` . Question is it should take magento's customer factory. But the error says my module's customer factory doesnt exists. Why so.

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: Hi Sohel as seems you are knowledge enough can you also please tell me if there are any kind of order needs to be maintained in constructor?...I mean if i need to add something new then i will add it at the end. But what if i want to override any function from `Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement` and then it shows  `Class namespace\module\Model\Customer\CustomerFactory does not exist` And i add like you said in the begining of the constructor because originally its in the beginning. That will work too?

Comment: Read -> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/factories.html

Comment: Ok. So i have written `\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,` the first line in the constructor. But it shows ` Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to namespace\module\Model\Customer\AccountManagement::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory, instance of Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy given`. Here event manager is the second one.

Comment: Most of the factory class are not exist. Magento created it run time under var/generation folder. This factory class is the main class. E.g: Magento/Customer/Model/Customer is the main class of CustomerFactory class

Comment: Read DI for Magento 2, how it's work